# Telegraf json_string_fields for string arrays

Tags: json, influxdb, telegraf

I have an influxdb, telegraf and Chronograf stack running and it is showing data coming from an MQTT broker. The data comes in JSON format and looks similar to this:

```
{
    "msgid": "id1",
    "senderid": "id2",
    "measures": [
        {
            "type": "O",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "type": "CO2",
            "value": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

To be able to analyze the different values I need telegraf to load the type and value strings. I have defined the `json_string_fields` like this:

```
json_string_fields = ["msgid","senderid","measures_0_type","measures_1_type","measures_0_value","measures_1_value"]
```

This way I can perform queries over the data but it is limited to the first two measures. Is there any way to define all the ocurrences of the array? Some kind of wildcard?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, did you find a solution? @jordi

Comment: No. I had to manually define the options thatwhere expected. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your time @jordi I did find out how to specify wildcards in json_string_fields look for the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use wildcards for json_string_fields you can do like for example:

```
json_string_fields = ["msgid","senderid","measures_?_type","measures_?_value"]
```

So if they go from 0 to 1000, you will get them all!